# R: import table as list

Tags: r, list, file-io

Being a newbie in R, I can I import "file.txt" that looks like this,

```
1:123-456_A_B
2:234-432_E_T
2:123456-987654_Q_E
35:98765-4321_P_H
```

into a list in R that looks like this:

```
[1] "1:123-456_A_B" "2:234-432_E_T" "2:123456-987654_Q_E" "35:98765-4321_P_H"
```

By the way, is the latter format called a "list" in R?

Thanks !

Comment: Awesome! Thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a `vector` of elements, this can be done easily with `scan`

```
v1 <- scan("file.txt", what = "", quiet=TRUE)
v1
#[1] "1:123-456_A_B"       "2:234-432_E_T"       "2:123456-987654_Q_E"
#[4] "35:98765-4321_P_H"
```

Answer (score -1):

as.vector(as.matrix(read.table("/path/to/file.txt", header = F, stringsAsFactors =F)))

By default, r will import as a data frame. So you have to convert it to a vector. What you want is a vector. List is something different. It is like a general holder of other objects of any type, like a "set" in mathematics.